# specifying date format when using $form->inputs() in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, date, input, helper

I am wondering if there is a way to specify the date format in the forms created using CakePHP's $form->inputs(); Please note that this is not the individual $form->input() but instead $form->inputs() that will create the whole form fields automagically.

Any input will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can pass the [usual options](http://book.cakephp.org/view/189/Automagic-Form-Elements) into `$form->inputs` that you would pass into `$form->input`.

For example, if you want to customise `field2` below, you make the field name the key and the options array the value:

```
echo $form->inputs(array(
    'field1',
    'field2' => array(
        'label' => 'Date and time',
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
        'minYear' => date('Y') - 1,
        'maxYear' => date('Y'),
        'empty' => true,
    ),
    'field3',
));
```

Comment: Hi deizel, thank you for your response... yes that works, but the thing is it defeats the purpose of $form->inputs() where I don't need to list all my fields.

If I only list the date fields that I want to format then it will only show the fields listed.